# Using TextFinder on a multi dimensional Range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, search, multidimensional-array

I last coded in javascript around 20 yrs ago, but a non-profit needed help with a basic appscript so I volunteered to help.  I'm stuck on a feature which involves searching a google sheet and returning values to a webpage.

The sheet has 3 columns and approx. 20,000 rows
Column A is ID
Column B is Name + Street (ex: John Doe - 1 Birch St)
Column C is Yes/No column

If user searches for "Birch", I want to return a 2 dimensional array where "Birch" (textSearch) appears in Column B and "Y" is in Column C.
I've played around with TextFinder and it works great to return the values in Column B that match, but I also need to eliminate rows where Column C = "Y"

In the code below, I've used textFinder on a range of B:C, but when I console.log RegMatch, it doesn't contain Column C.  I think it has to do with the map line, but I'm not sure how to fix that and check for Y in Column C as well. Thanks so much for reading!

```
    function Search(txtSearch, userID, userName, userEmail){
        const sheetName = "Sheet1";
        const range = "B:C";
        const RegMatch = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID)
            .getSheetByName(sheetName)
            .getRange(range)
            .createTextFinder(txtSearch)
            .matchEntireCell(false)
            .matchCase(false)
            .findAll()
            .map((r) => r.getValue())  
        return RegMatch;
    }
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I have 2 questions. 1. In your question, you say `Column C is Yes/No column`. But, you also say `I want to return a 2 dimensional array where "Birch" (textSearch) appears in Column B and "Y" is in Column C.`. What values are in column "C"? 2. In your script, the arguments of `userID, userName, userEmail` are not used. What will you do about them? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Thanks - TheWizEd's suggestion worked perfectly. I've been piecing together this website by copying and pasting code. I thought the map was the issue but couldn't figure out how to corrrect the syntax. Thanks so much!

Comment: Click the checkmark button on the left of the answer to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The `.findAll()` will only return a range like "B3", so you need to expand the range using `.offset()` and `.getValues()`.  And since `.getValues()` return a 2D array you need to extract the first element of the array.

```
.map((r) => r.offset(0,0,1,2).getValues()[0])
```

Comment: Thanks so much - this worked perfectly!! Really appreciate you and everyone else who takes the time to help inexperienced people like me :)